# What leads to a no suitable image found error on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, xcode, debugging

I followed Chris Hanson's [advice](http://chanson.livejournal.com/119578.html) about debugging framework unit tests in Xcode 3.1, but  when trying to run the custom executable, the program crashes, stating the below error message [substituted $(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR) for the real location of the build products].

```
2009-03-02 19:56:03.414 otest[28059:10b] Error loading
    $(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR)/Debug/Unit Tests.octest/
    Contents/MacOS/Unit Tests: dlopen($(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR_)/Unit
    Tests.octest/Contents/MacOS/Unit Tests, 265):
    no suitable image found. Did find:
    $(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR)/Unit Tests.octest/Contents/MacOS/Unit Tests:
    mach-o, but wrong architecture
2009-03-02 19:56:03.561 otest[28059:10b] The test bundle at
    $(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR)/Unit Tests.octest could not be loaded because
    it is built for a different architecture than the currently-running
    test rig (which is running as unknown).
2009-03-02 19:56:03.568 otest[28060:203] *** NSTask: Task create for path
    '$(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR)/Unit Tests.octest/Contents/MacOS/Unit Tests'
    failed: 8, "Exec format error". Terminating temporary process.
```

My question is, what leads to the *no suitable image found. Did find: ...* error message and how can I get the *otest* executable to run correctly so that I can debug my framework unit tests?

Is there an easier way to do this with out using otest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

otest is running just fine. The error is telling you that it can't load *the test bundle*, and that the reason why it can't load the test bundle is because it doesn't know what architecture it's running as.

The solution is to set `ARCHPREFERENCE` in otest's environment. You can do this in Xcode's custom executable editor. Set it to the architecture you want to run tests under.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, Peter!

Answer (score 0):

The line `Unit Tests.octest could not be loaded because it is built for a different architecture than the currently-running test rig` would suggest that the dependencies were built for a different system - perhaps it's a PPC / Intel mismatch or the like?