# MapKit framework linkage error: Reason: no suitable image found. Did find mach-o, but wrong filetype

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to set up https://github.com/EvgenyKarkan/EKAlgorithms repository to be built on Travis. I am experimenting on my fork of this repo.

Inside EKAlgorithmsApp I have OS X Cocoa Unit Testing Bundle test target which works perfectly fine on my local machine. However on Travis I see weird error message which prevents the project from being built successfully:

```
2014-04-01 14:08:55.287 xctest[1551:303] The test bundle at /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest could not be loaded because an unanticipated error occurred: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/MapKit

Referenced from: /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs

Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:

/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/MapKit: mach-o, but wrong filetype) UserInfo=0x100402870 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/MapKit

Referenced from: /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs

Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:

/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/MapKit: mach-o, but wrong filetype, NSBundlePath=/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}

2014-04-01 14:08:55.295 xctest[1553:203] *** NSTask: Task create for path '/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs' failed: 22, "Invalid argument". Terminating temporary process.

** TEST SUCCEEDED **

The command "make ci" exited with 0.

Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

---

Here is the one of the last builds logs - this error in its bottom.

https://travis-ci.org/stanislaw/EKAlgorithms/builds/22054216#L751

---

I've tried to set `ARCHPREFERENCE=x86_64` as suggested in similar topic: [What leads to a no suitable image found error on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617084/what-leads-to-a-no-suitable-image-found-error-on-mac-os-x) and still got error but a bit different:

```
2014-04-02 04:10:15.680 xctest[1530:303] The test bundle at /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest could not be loaded because an unanticipated error occurred: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/MapKit

Referenced from: /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs

Reason: image not found) UserInfo=0x10010caa0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/Versions/A/MapKit

Referenced from: /Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs

Reason: image not found, NSBundlePath=/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}

2014-04-02 04:10:15.688 xctest[1532:203] *** NSTask: Task create for path '/Users/travis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/EKAlgorithmsApp-gsexyadvxwaizwcyfyqalajrgzrr/Build/Products/Debug/EKAlgorithmsSpecs.xctest/Contents/MacOS/EKAlgorithmsSpecs' failed: 22, "Invalid argument". Terminating temporary process.

** TEST SUCCEEDED **
```

Here is the build log of this alternative: https://travis-ci.org/stanislaw/EKAlgorithms/builds/22094380#L743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer: it was just the fact that Travis build machines do not support Mac OS X 10.9 yet. Currently they are 10.8.5 but have 10.9 SDKs listed - this was the reason of my confusion.